# how to find one date with any format after colon ':' using python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract specific date string from a whole sentence.

For example : `string = 'Smith Born: Wednesday October 10 1975 Died: Wednesday December December 20 2018, Service will be held ayz location on Saturday December 23 2018'`.

From above sentences how can i extract 'Born date (any format) but will always be in `"Born: Date"` format. Similarly Died date again any date format.

I am using Python. I wanted to know is there any way I can use `regex` and `datetime` `parse`, for example:

I am finding Age as `re.compile('Age ([0-9]*)')` if the `Age 32` then the above code will be used to find `32`. Is there any way i can use `re.compile('Born: (parse(datetime))')` or any other option would be great.. thank you

`string = 'Smith Born: Wednesday October 10 1975 Died: Wednesday December December 20 2018, Service will be held ayz location on Saturday December 23 2018'`.

Extract born date and died date. Any date format.

I am trying `re.compile('Born: (parse(datetime))')` but dont know how to compile the parse datetime library in re.compiler.

Comment: You have to put *some* restrictions on what format the date can have. Could it be a timestamp encoded in binary? :)

Comment: Are you trying to get these details with a single expression, or do you plan to use two different regexps? BTW, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aqyHDk/2). Also, [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/p0074o)

Comment: @timgeb i am sure it wont be a timestamp as it is a random string that a user inputs. Thanks.. WiktorStribiżew. i tried splitting using ':' i found the solution but it was a lot messy. joe has a perfect solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty ugly, but for short texts you could run progressively shorter strings past `dateutil.parser`:

```
import dateutil

def extract_date(text):
    while True:
        try:
            date = dateutil.parser.parse(text)
            return date
        except:
            pass
        end = text.rfind(" ")
        if end == -1:
            return None
        text = text[:end]
    return None

def following(pattern, text):
    start = text.find(pattern)
    if start == -1:
        return None
    return text[start + len(pattern):]

text = 'Smith Born: Wednesday October 10 1975 Died: Wednesday December December 20 2018, Service will be held ayz location on Saturday December 23 2018'
print(extract_date(following("Born:", text)))
print(extract_date(following("Died:", text)))
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. I know dates can be messy and there are no restrictions on date format as it is a random string that a user inputs. this solution is perfect.. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. (And please consider selecting it as the answer!)